# C Language Convention - Non-explicit Conversion vs Explicit Conversion

Tags: c, type-conversion

For instance,

```
float get_at_index(ring_buffer_t *buffer, ring_buffer_size_t index) {
    if (index >= ring_buffer_num_items(buffer)) { /* No items at index */
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* Add index to pointer */
    ring_buffer_size_t data_index = ((buffer->tail_index + index) & RING_BUFFER_MASK);
    return buffer->buffer[data_index];
}
```

### Does it make a difference to do `return (float)buffer->buffer[data_index]`?

Where `buffer->buffer[data_index]` is a float array.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] and show what you are asking?

Comment: You have not shown us what the definition of `ring_buffer_t` is, so we do not know what the type of `buffer->buffer[data_index]`, so we do not know what conversion will or will not be performed in `return buffer->buffer[data_index];`. Edit the question to show the definition of that structure, and edit it to show the actual exact text of code you are asking about (“the last line with (float) conversion”), not a description of what that text would be.

Comment: If. perhaps, you are asking about the `return 0;` statement, because `0` is an integer literal, then its OK, the zero integer literal will get automatically converted to `float 0.00` on return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the code in your question:

```
float get_at_index(<parameters>) {
    <code>
    return buffer->buffer[data_index];
}
```

and you're asking whether it would make any difference if the last line were:

```
    return (float)buffer->buffer[data_index];
```

The answer is no.

A `return` statement in a function returning `float` will, if possible, implicitly convert the expression to `float`. An explicit conversion (i.e., a cast) will perform exactly the same conversion.

It happens that the types that can be implicitly converted to `float` are the same as the types that can be explicitly converted to `float`, i.e., the arithmetic types. There are other conversions that can only be done with a cast, such as conversions from one pointer type to another, or a pointer to an integer, or an integer to a pointer (with some exceptions that aren't relevant here).

One drawback of using a cast here is that if you later decide to change the return type of the function to, say, `double`, you'd still be explicitly converting the expression to `float`, and the result of that conversion would then be implicitly converted to `double`. Letting the compiler figure out the target type is often safer than specifying it yourself.

A quick Google search shows a possible definition of `ring_buffer_t` as a structure with a `buffer` member of type `char*`. If you're using that definition or one like it, you're converting a `char` value to `float`. That's rarely a sensible thing to do. It's likely that it would make more sense for your `get_at_index` function to return a `char` result rather than a `float` result. But it's impossible to be sure without seeing more of your code. (I'm not suggesting you post it here, because it's not directly relevant to your question.)

Also, the title of your question is "C Language - Non-explicit Convertion of Pointers". There are no pointer conversions in the code you showed us. (If `buffer->buffer[data_index]` were of pointer type, it would be illegal to convert it to `float`, either implicitly or explicitly.)

Comment: As for actual conversions involving pointers, only `void*` conversions are allowed to be implicit. No other implicit pointer conversions exist in the C language (C17 6.5.4 and 6.5.16.1).

Comment: @Lundin Good point. I've added some weasel words to cover that. (An integer-to-pointer conversion can be implicit if the integer expression is a null pointer constant; I won't waste time debating whether that counts as a "pointer conversion".)

Comment: Yes, your answer was very helpful.
What you mentioned in the beginning was exactly what I meant, and I was taking into consideration of adding up the extra casting can be redundant but was not sure if I am missing anything. @KeithThompson

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you intend to return a pointer to a float in your `get_at_index` function, and have made a typo in the function's definition. In that case, no, you would not need to explicitly cast the pointer into a float pointer.